# CSRF token missing or incorrect . How to resolve this error?

Tags: django, authentication, csrf-token

I am new to django. I am creating a website using django. I have provided register and login functionality to my website.

Only Problem is after sucessfull login, whenever i reload a browser accidently it asks me this ques
[about re-submitting details again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exirk.jpg)

and then if click on continue , it shows me this error page.
[csrf token missing or incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV2yq.jpg)

Please tell me what should i do to avoid this error?

Comment: After successful register or login redirect to a new page or clear the data of form.

Comment: how to clear data of form?

Answer (score 0):

```
include {% csrf_token %} inside the form tag in the template and Just make sure, is there UserWarning in console like?: "A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value. This is usually caused by not using RequestContext."
if for any reason you are using render_to_response on Django 1.3 and above replace it with the render function. Replace this:

# Don't use this on Django 1.3 and above
return render_to_response('contact.html', {'form': form})
With this:

return render(request, 'contact.html', {form: form})
The render function was introduced in Django version 1.3 - if you are using an ancient version like 1.2 or below you must use render_to_response with a a RequestContext:

# Deprecated since version 2.0
return render_to_response('contact.html', {'form': form},
                   context_instance=RequestContext(request))`enter code here`
```

Comment: I am using render function only . still getting that error . Plz help

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you an example you can try it such way:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect

def login_view(request):
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            user_obj = form.cleaned_data.get('user_obj')
            login(request, user_obj)
            return redirect('home') # if you want to redirect same page then, return redirect('this function name in urls.py')

    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Try this way. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much bro ! Somehow it worked ! I just repalced return render line with redirect home line as yours in my  views.py code !